# Xcode sort array by specific (NSString) dictionary key (like sql query)

Tags: sql, arrays, xcode, sorting, nssortdescriptor

For example I want to sort following array based on "fruit" in the sequence of orange, kiwi, apple, mango. After that the array sort follow the ascending sequence of name among the same "fruit".

```
    <__NSArrayM 0x8aaaaa0>(
{
    "unique" = 1;
    "fruit" = "apple";
    "name"  = "James";
},{
    "unique" = 2;
    "fruit" = "apple";
    "name"  = "Jason";
}, {
    "unique" = 3;
    "fruit" = "orange";
    "name"  = "Peter";
} ,{
    "unique" = 4;
    "fruit" = "kiwi;
    "name"  = "Amy";
} ,{
    "unique" = 5;
    "fruit" = "kiwi";
    "name"  = "Lionel";
} ,{
    "unique" = 6;
    "fruit" = "mango";
    "name"  = "Jacky";
}
```

Comment: Any nssortdescriptor method beside sort by for loop?

Comment: Hi mate, Please let me know if you have found the answer.
Need the answer badly.